# Creating Jira issues through Python script: trouble with component, duedate and fixversion field EDITED

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm currently writing a simple Python script which reads data from an Excel sheet and creates Jira tasks based on that data. I've got the Excel data-reading part working and the Jira task creation mostly as well, but am struggling with a couple of fields.

The following fields are mandatory for our Jira tasks:

1. project
2. issue type
3. summary
4. parent watcher (custom field)
5. priority
6. external bid (custom field)
7. fix version/s
8. component
9. due date

I got the first six working with the following line of code in Python:

```
issue = jira.create_issue(project=pro, summary=sum, issuetype=type, customfield_13700 = { "name": parent }, priority = {'name': priority}, customfield_12501 = external_bid )
```

However, I am not sure how to fill in the other parameters of the jira.create_issue function for the fix versions/s, component and due date bid fields.

I've tried many different things:

For the fix version field:

```
issue = jira.create_issue(fixversion=fixversion )
issue = jira.create_issue(fixversion = {'name': fixversion})
issue = jira.create_issue(fixversion = {'value': fixversion})
```

which all results in the following error:
*"errors":{"fixversion":"Field 'fixversion' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}*

For the component field:

```
issue = jira.create_issue(component = component )
issue = jira.create_issue(component = {'name': component} )
issue = jira.create_issue(fixversion = {'value': component})
```

Which again all results in the following error:
*errors":{"component":"Field 'component' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}*

For the due date:

```
issue = jira.create_issue(duedate = duedate)
issue = jira.create_issue(duedate = {'name': duedate} )
issue = jira.create_issue(duedate = {'value': duedate} )
```

Which gives the following error:
*TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable*

At this point, I've tried a host of different things and looked a bunch of stuff up, most of which point to [this page](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/?_ga=2.14194423.1191112478.1550594923-618955561.1550154667#creating-an-issue-examples):

*JIRA projects may contain many different issue types. Some issue screens have different requirements for fields in a new issue. This information is available through the ‘createmeta’ method. Further examples are available [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/?_ga=2.14194423.1191112478.1550594923-618955561.1550154667#creating-an-issue-examples).*

Which isn't really helpful for me. Anybody have any idea how to best proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable` is issued when you try to serialize a datetime object into a JSON object.

The *`duedate`* value you use is a datetime object. Whenever you try to dump a dictionary containing a datetime object to a JSON object, you will encounter this error. Example below:

```
import datetime
test = {}
test['date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
import json
json.dumps(test)
```

To avoid this error, convert your datetime object to an object that is accepted by the Javascript Object Notation (JSON) standard. Such as a string.

```
test['date'] = str(datetime.datetime.now()) 
json.dumps(test)
```

Do note that direct conversion from your datetime object might not fit the JIRA format for accepted dates. Use the correct format when casting to string (give the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation a look)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It was fixed with the two following lines:

`duedate = str(getCellValue(ws, i, eColumn.DUE_DATE.value).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`
`issue = jira.create_issue(duedate = duedate + "T00:00:00.000-0500")`

Comment: For the other issues, a member from the Atlassian team has helped me out. In essence, you need to pass these parameters as an array. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Creating-Jira-issues-through-Python-script-trouble-with/qaq-p/1014827#U1019899